# failed to load config from /app/vite.config.ts whiles running vite-react on docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, vite

Whiles running this command:

```
docker run -p 5173:5173 -v "$(pwd):/app" -v /app/node_modules react-docker
```

It throws the below error message:

```
> react-docker@0.0.0 dev
> vite --host

failed to load config from /app/vite.config.ts
error when starting dev server:
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/vite.config.ts.timestamp-1710029032313-304203094a5fc.mjs'
```

I try running  this:

```
docker run -p 5173:5173 -v "$(pwd):/app" -v /app/node_modules --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" react-docker
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up the permissions:

```
docker run -p 5173:5173 -v "$(pwd):/app" -v/app/node_modules -u "$(id -u): $(id -g)" --User initialization: native response-docker chown - R " $ ( id - u ): $ ( id - g )" /job
```

This command is:

The character begins.
Set your current directory to /app inside the container.
Installs the node_modules folder.
Set the container user to be you.
Change the owner of all files in /app to your file.

*Use --mount::.*

```
docker run -p 5173:5173 --mount type=bind, source="$(pwd)", target=/process, uid=$(id-u), gid=$(id-g) response-docker
```

This command gives you access to your current directory in /app.

If problem not soleve try check this:

- Error named vite.config.ts.
- Error in Vite configuration.